# Is any way to pass WebSense?

Tags: security

Is any way to pass WebSense ?

Comment: Huh? Do you mean bypass/disable?

Comment: @Nifle: Presumably. I have a subdomain on my website for the purpose of bypassing stupid filters, but I only use it when the company maintaining the lists blocks something dumb like imgur.com or appspot.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably this is a Websense filtering service at your company/school/library/somewhere-someone-other-than-you-pays-for-bandwidth-and-PCs?

There will be a way for authorised people at the company who have a legitimate reason to bypass part or all of the Websense filtering to do so, if you do have a legitimate reason then you should be able to apply to get on that list.

Otherwise the filtering is there for a reason and any attempts to bypass it are against the wishes of the legitimate owners and maintainers of the resources that you're using and not really something that should be discussed here.